# Biasing an NMOS to get rid of \$V_{th}\$

Tags: voltage-divider, zener, bias, nmos

So here's a common way of cancelling out the \$V_{th}\$ in an NMOS. Am I better of use a good quality zener (in series with a resistor) or stick with voltage divider R1 and R2 below.

Assuming we can have very low tolerances for R1 and R2 and we can choose the value of a zener continuously (rather than the preferred values). Which is still better?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you put a zener diode in place of R2 you would certainly get a very stable voltage on the gate. In fact, it would be so stable that the AC input signal will be clamped at the zener regulation voltage. This makes the circuit into a very poor AC amplifier.

Comment: But you would get a signal at the output though, that would be the noise of the zener diode ! So if you wanted to build a noise generator, there you go :-)

Comment: Good call LOL!!!!

Comment: Fair enough, I've considered cases of it being non-Common amplifiers (resistor and NMOS directly on ground and supply) and even in those cases it just not a generic solution.